# Method proc with parameters

Tags: crystal-lang

Is possible to use method proc with parameters in Crystal ?

Something like:

```
def foo(baz)
  puts "#{baz} foo!"
end

proc = ->foo

proc.call "Hi"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If the method has arguments, you must specify their types:

```
proc = ->foo(String)
proc.call "Hi" # Hi foo!
```

Find more examples at [crystal docs](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/literals/proc.html).