# What is a proc in Crystal Lang?

Tags: crystal-lang

I read the documentation on Procs in the Crystal Language book on the organizations’s site. What exactly is a proc? I get that you define argument and return types and use a call method to call the proc which makes me think it’s a function. But why use a proc? What is it for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*You cannot pass methods into other methods (but you can pass procs into methods), and methods cannot return other methods (but they can return procs).*

Also Proc captures variables from the scope where it has been defined:

```
a = 1
b = 2

proc = ->{ a + b }

def foo(proc)
  bar(proc)
end

def bar(proc)
  a = 5
  b = 6
  1 + proc.call
end

puts bar(proc) # => 4
```

A powerful feature is to convert a block to Proc and pass it to a method, so you can [forward it](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/block_forwarding.html):

```
def int_to_int(&block : Int32 -> Int32)
  block
end

proc = int_to_int { |x| x + 1 }
proc.call(1) #=> 2
```

Also, as @Johannes Müller commented, Proc can be used as a [closure](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/closures.html):

```
def minus(num)
  ->(n : Int32) { num - n }
end

minus_20 = minus(20)
minus_20.call(7) # => 13
```

Comment: The example about block forwarding is not really great because it doesn't actually use a Proc's unique features. You can do the same with a plain block (using `yield`). The power of a block is that it can be stored (for example in an instance variable) and forms a closure.

Comment: @JohannesMüller, thank you, I've updated the answer.

Comment: BTW, you can use a proc method as well, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46728999/7450793

Answer (score 3):

The language reference explains [Proc](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/literals/proc.html) pretty well actually:

> A [Proc](https://crystal-lang.org/api/Proc.html) represents a function pointer with an optional context (the closure data).

So yes, a proc is essentially like a function. In contrast to a plain block, it essentially holds a reference to a block so it can be stored and passed around and also provides a closure.

Answer (score 3):

A Proc is simply a function/method without a name. You can pass it around as a variable, and it can refer to variables in it's enclosing scope (it's a closure). They are often used as a way of passing method blocks around as variables.